# How to read Meteor settings from a build plugin

Tags: meteor, meteor-packages, meteor-plugin

I'm currently working on a package for Meteor that includes a build plugin. I need to access configurations from the settings file.

However `Meteor.settings` doesn't work (`Meteor is not defined`) and `process.env.METEOR_SETTINGS` also doesn't exist.

Is there any way for my plugin to access the settings file?

Comment: Are you importing Meteor? `import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';`

Comment: I wasn't, but once I import Meteor, the value of `Meteor.settings` is `{ public: {} }`, so plugins must run before Meteor loads settings.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that despite the documentation discussing the use of --settings, it doesn't work in a production environment, as often command line options are not available.

So the solution is to use environment variables, which are available only on the server.

server code, meteor methods:

```
eor methods
Meteor.methods({
    getPJS: function() {
        return process.env.PEERJS_SERVER;
    },
```

client code

```
var PJS = Meteor.call("getPJS");
```

So you can make those environment variables available on the client if you need them.